# Regular Expressions matching difficulty

Tags: regex, vba, excel

My current regex:

```
([\d]*)([^\d]*[\d][a-z]*-[\d]*)([\d][a-z?])(.?)
```

Right so I am attempting to make regex match a string based on: a count that can be any amount of number from 0-1million then followed by a number then sometimes a letter then - then any number for numbers followed by the same number and sometimes a letter then sometimes a letter. example of strings it should match:

```
1921-1220104081741b
192123212a-1220234104081742ab
```

an example of what it should return based on above (this is 2 examples it shouldn't read both lines.)

```
(192) (1-122010408174) (1) (b)
(19212321) (2a-122023410408174) (2a) (b)
```

My current regex works with the second one but it returns (1b) in the first when I would like it to return (1) (b) but also return (2a) in the case of the second one or the case of:

```
1926h-1220104081746h  Should Return: (192) (6h-122010408174) (6h)
```

Not 100% sure if its possible, sense I'm fairly new to regex.  For reference I'm doing this in excel-vba if there is any other way to do this easier.

Comment: Since you're doing this with Excel VBA, what code do you have so far? Or is your question *how* to use regex with VBA?

Comment: Your requirements with regards to the final character are not clear. In your first example, `b` stands alone in its capture group. In the third example, `h` is grouped with `6`. Which one is correct?

Comment: @BruceWayne the program over 4k lines, but my question is just in regards of how to change my current regex to match the cases ive listed above.

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder both are correct if you look at the first example it has (1-122010408174)  but in the last example it has (6h-122010408174) if there is a letter grouped with the number before the - then it should also be grouped at the end but if not it is used for something else so it should be separated in the case of (b)

Comment: @Persiden Are you trying to get something similar to this? https://regex101.com/r/mO3eE6/1 - `(\d*)(\D*(\d[a-z]*)-\d*)(\3)([a-z])?`

Comment: *"any number for numbers followed by the same number"* I don't fully understand what you mean by this. Can you show an example for this part only?

Comment: you say that the first part is a number "from 0-1million", but then in the second example, the number is 19,212,321, which is larger than 1 million. The other parts of your description are equally imprecise. Can you clean up your description to be more specific and provide a couple more examples?

Comment: So your question is about RegEx, not necessarily Excel/VBA at all? You're just looking for the right pattern to use?

Comment: @BruceWayne it's still relatively valid to know that it's the RegExp class imported from VBScript, since it is a particularly limited flavor.

Comment: To better clarify my question the regex should match (one to infinite)(A number, Zero or one Letter, there character '-'  ,one to infinite numbers)(the same patter before '-')(zero or one letter)  , but it seems @JoshCrozier has done exactly what I needed this will work nicely, I had no idea you could reference previous matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could capture the character(s) before the dash character, and then back reference that match.

In the expression below, `\3` would match what was matched by the 3rd capturing group:

```
(\d*)((\d[a-z]*)-\d*)(\3)([a-z])?
```

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/aU0oA6/1)

[image]

Output after merging the capture groups:

```
1921-1220104081741b
(192) (1-122010408174) (1) (b)
```

```
192123212a-1220234104081742ab
(19212321) (2a-122023410408174) (2a) (b)
```

```
1926h-1220104081746h
(192) (6h-122010408174) (6h)
```

#### Example:

Disregard the JS. Here is the output after merging the capture groups:

```js
var strings = ['1921-1220104081741b', '192123212a-1220234104081742ab', '1926h-1220104081746h'], exp = /(\d*)((\d[a-z]*)-\d*)(\3)([a-z])?/;

strings.forEach(function(str) {
  var m = str.match(exp);
  
  snippet.log(str);
  snippet.log('(' + m[1] + ') ('+ m[2] + ') (' + m[4] + ') (' + (m[5]||'') + ')');
  snippet.log('---');
});
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice trick with nested capture groups! Is the `\D*` necessary? It doesn't appear to be part of the OP's requirements in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are saying with "followed by the same number" is that the piece right before the dash is repeated as your third capture group. I would suggest implementing this by splitting up your second capture group and then using a backreference:

```
([\d]*)([\d][a-z]*)-([\d]*)(\2)(.?)
```

For your three examples:

```
1921-1220104081741b
192123212a-1220234104081742ab
1926h-1220104081746h
```

This results in:

```
(192)      (1)  - (122010408174)    (1)  (b)
(19212321) (2a) - (122023410408174) (2a) (b)
(192)      (6h) - (122010408174)    (6h) ()
```

...and you can join the two middle groups back together to get the hyphenated term you wanted.